# Can I have 2 foreign keys in table pointing the same column?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I have a table transact representing a financial transaction between 2 funds:

```
CREATE TABLE transact 
(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    src_fund_id INT ,
    dest_fund_id INT ,
    units FLOAT, 
    FOREIGN KEY (src_fund_id) REFERENCES funds(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (dest_fund_id) REFERENCES funds(id)
);
```

Both source and destination funds come from the same table `Funds`. It seems impossible to make both FKs point to the same column. In this case, should I design my DB in a different way?

Comment: Why do you think that you even need foreign key references in the first place in this table?  Can you add some more description about what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can have two foreign keys for different columns to the same table.  This is standard in SQL.

Your code is fine, as written.  Of course, this assumes that a `funds` table exists with a column called `id` and whose type is `int`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=df34a56455e2a492f1038356504bf4da) is a db<>fiddle that shows that your code works.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Here is my db script [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=453fd36a4e16190a2e796037e4b51d95)

Originally, I use it as in-memory db for Hibernate with Spring Boot.
Attempts to execute the script on the page finish with errors for lines that I consider 100% correct.

Comment: @Krzysztof . . . I think db<>fiddle requires that MySQL create statements be in different code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create two FKs points the same column.
But the best practice adds one column in the table
**transact** contain both columns Ids in the table **funds** comma separated.

Comment: Makes sense, but how in this case should it be mapped to Hibernate entity?
@ Entity
@ Table(name = "transact")
public class Transact implements Serializable {

    @ Id
    @ GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private int src_fund_id;
    private int dest_fund_id;
    private float units;

Comment: For the Entity we can't define this column as  FK for table **transact**.
According to your business, if it is possible to add the FK for **transact** on the table **funds** it will bettter.

Comment: Thanks Eman,  it is possible to add the FK for transact on the table funds, as you suggested, but I don't think it's a good idea. Transaction has always 2 funds, while a fund can have many transactions.